# Hyperledger Fabric create own network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am able to create my crypto-config and channel-artifacts with one organisation and two peers. How can I create similar environment like chaincode-docker-devmode (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples), where I can run my chaincode locally. What should my docker-compose.yaml file contain.

Comment: How should the entire file and folder structure look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your chaincode will need to run in docker containers. It depends on how you are writing your chaincode logic- if you are using Hyperledger Composer (recommended) you need additional docker contains running couch-db, these store the ledger data, 1 couch-db per peer. If you are writing the chaincode by hand you do not need these additional containers.

You need to make a yaml file containing the network topography. I have included the yaml file in the first-network example provided by hyperledger. (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/first-network) is a link to the github- I would recommend checking this out

```html
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "6984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1

  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "7984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb2

  couchdb3:
    container_name: couchdb3
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "8984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb3
```

Comment: I am writing by hand. now when I am trying to run my docker-compose-cli.yaml file then i am getting an output as[docker-com pose-cli.yaml][1] output. And now assuming that my chaincode is up with my peers if i am trying to execute the docker exec -it chaincode bash in the terminal I get the output as [Chaincode error][2]. Can you help me resolve this.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hel19.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RgP2.png

Comment: The chaincode is not on the peers yet. If you are not using Composer you can remove the containers titled couch-db*. Your docker yaml file and crypto config need to mention the same docker containers- guessing that is the issue because you docker network is not communicating

Comment: At this point I would clone the first network directory- get that example running, then add in your customizations.